# How can i get my PHP SoapClient to Authenticate with Digest

Tags: php, vb.net, soap, asmx, digest

I currently have a vb.net ASMX web service hosted on IIS along with a PHP page which is calling the web service via a SoapClient.

I need to authenticate the webservice against ActiveDirectory and i figured the easiest way to do this would be to enable Digest Authentication on IIS and allow the user to enter their AD username/password into the PHP page and send this authentication in the SoapHeaders.

I am not really quite sure how to go about this, especially when trying to contact the WSDL (which is also behind the Digest Authentication).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT: What i've tried:**

**SERVICE_URL** points to http://mypage/service.asmx?wsdl

Attempt 1: User and Pass as MD5

```
$options = array(
        'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
        'realm' => 'myrealm',
        'login' => $_SESSION['authUser'],
        'password' => $_SESSION['authPass']
    );
try { $client = new SoapClient(SERVICE_URL, $options); }
```

Attempt 2: Auth is the 'user':'realm':'pass' as MD5:

```
$options = array(
        'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
        'login' => $_SESSION['auth']
    );
try { $client = new SoapClient(SERVICE_URL, $options); }
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have tried so far? Adding the authorization in the headers _should_ do the trick, but its implementation will depend on how you are making the API calls.

Comment: Updated with my attempts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add headers to your soap client using `SoapHeader()` class/object ([SoapHeader() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php)) and soap object operator `__setSoapHeaders()` ([__setSoapHeaders() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.setsoapheaders.php)).

Your request would look something like this:

```
<?php

    $options = array(
        'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST,
        'realm' => 'myrealm',
        'login' => $_SESSION['authUser'],
        'password' => $_SESSION['authPass']
    );
    try { 
        $client = new SoapClient(SERVICE_URL, $options);

        // create and populate header array
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader('MYNAMESPACE', 
            'authentication',
            'SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST');
        $headers[] = new SoapHeader('MYNAMESPACE', 
            'realm',
            'myrealm');

        $client->__setSoapHeaders($headers); // set headers
        $client->__soapCall("echoVoid", null); // make soap call
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. Unfortunately this does not work as the client fails initially when attempting to contact the WSDL, as this is also behind the Digest Authentication. Any recommendations for setting the authentication prior to contacting the WSDL?